# Wrong tickposition and data point in highstock chart

Tags: highcharts

I found a problem in high stock timeline chart , I created chart with 1 hour data every 5 min i get data so totally i have 12 data points in 1 hour.Timeline chart creates and plots the data   but tick position in x-axis and data point for particular time showing wrong .
Take if tick position is 10:00 data is showing before / after the tick position  .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Have you tried to set tickInterval? http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickInterval

Comment: Yes i tried but response is same!

Comment: Could you recreate your example in the jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Here you can see [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AWTyT/) Zoom into 8:00 - 12:00 take look at 10:30,10:35,10:45,10:50,11:00.

Comment: The problem is with your data, because as I see, you have i.e 10.41 Mon May 13 2013 10:41:00. Please take look at timestamp: 1368441660000 which returns this date as 10.41

Comment: Yes you are right my time stamp data is wrong. Thanks Sebastian